# How to update sdk android using notepad++

Tags: android, sdk, notepad++

Recently I received a message from google that I should update the sdk of my apk , Unfortunately I lost my code source I only have the apk so I am using the apktool to change specific things, but I have no Idea how to update the SDK using NOTEPAD++

Answer (score 0):

You can't change just de SDK. You need to change de SDK in your app and then compile the app and probably update the libraries, so... even you change code lines you need to compile the project, change the version and signed the new APK.

Comment: So , is there any possibility to change the SDK and the lebraries using the NOTEPAD++ ? I can Compile the project using the apktools but i have no Idea how to update the following stuffs like updating libraries ?